# How to modify aws cli command output

Tags: shell, command-line, jq, aws-cli, aws-userpools

I am using below command **to list the UserPool Names**.

```
aws cognito-idp list-user-pools --max-results 60 --region us-west-2 --query 'UserPools[*].{Names:Name}'
```

Now my all UserPool Names contains `cust_` as prefix. And i want to remove that from whole list.

I know i can achieve this using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).
But how?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please follow the mcve guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you output with `--output text`, it will become a text list.

You could then use standard Linux tools such as piping it through `| cut -c6-`

This will provide character #6 onwards for each line.

Full command would be something like:

```
aws cognito-idp list-user-pools --max-results 60 --region us-west-2 --query 'UserPools[*].[{Names:Name}]' --output text | cut -c6-
```

Comment: Converting output to text is looks complex for the case of many userpools. It will only give `ci` if my userpool name is `cust_ci`.
I want Modified JSON.

Comment: That was what you requested in your question: _"Now my all UserPool Names contains cust\_ as prefix. And i want to remove that from whole list."_ Perhaps you can edit your question and provide some input & output samples if you want a different answer.

Comment: If i run from command line `aws cognito-idp list-user-pools --max-results 60 --region $region --query 'UserPools[*].{Names:Name}' --output text | cut -c6-` 
Then it is giving each userpool name in new line.
But while running same command from shell script, It gives my names with space saperated. 
`echo \'aws cognito-idp list-user-pools --max-results 60 --region $region --query 'UserPools[*].{Names:Name}' --output text | cut -c6-\`` 
Any idea?

Comment: Try `UserPools[*].[{Names:Name}]` as per https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/914

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. I've seen that before, never knew how to solve it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171304/discussion-between-jayesh-dhandha-and-john-rotenstein).

Comment: For the moment i have appended `| tr " " "\n"` in my command. Now it is giving me desired output. :)